# Google spreadsheet - Sum data of array within date range match row and column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets

My data looks like this:

[image]

I wanted to sum a range that match 3 conditions

- Country
- DateRange >= Date1 and DateRange <= Date2

Tried index match for only one date and it worked, but for date range the formula keeps giving error.

Comment: is this excel or google spreadsheet. Only use the appropriate tag.

Comment: I've just tried this and it works **`IF(J3>=B1, IF(K3<=B1, SUM(B2:B9), "NA"), "NA")`** (where `J3` and `K3` hold a date). What is your formula?

Answer (score 0):

IF you have the date range defined in cells J1 and K1, then this should work, provided the Dates are of the same Format (all dates or all text, etc):

```
=sum(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2, MATCH(J1,B1:G1, 0)+1, 4) & ":" & REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(2, MATCH(K1,B1:G1, 0)+1, 4), "[A-Z]+")))
```

INDIRECT() allows us to define a range from text.  This uses a combination of ADDRESS() and MATCH() to build the first part of the range and it uses REGEXEXTRACT() to remove the row reference in the second part of the range.

Breaking this down from the inside, assuming J1 = 2017-07-28 and K1 = 2017-07-30, we have the first MATCH returning a value of 2 for the second column in the range B1:G1 matching the contents of J1:

```
MATCH(J1,B1:G1, 0)
```

Since we are starting our column count at column B we need to add one to that, making the associated ADDRESS evaluate to C2 as the function is looking for the second row, third column and the 4 tells it to return a relative value and therefore not include the $ characters:

```
ADDRESS(2, 2+1, 4)
```

The second use the the ADDRESS() and MATCH() functions is surrounded in REGEXEXTRACT() to remove the Row reference and evlauates down as follows

```
REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(2, MATCH(K1,B1:G1, 0)+1), "[A-Z]+")
```

to

```
REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(2, 4+1), "[A-Z]+")
```

to

```
REGEXEXTRACT("E2", "[A-Z]+")
```

Where this returns only the characters A-Z as many times as they occure, so AZ will be returned if ADRESS() evlautaes to AZ2.

This leaves us with the INDIRECT() which now becomes:

```
INDIRECT("C2 & ":" & "E")
```

or

```
INDIRECT("C2:E")
```

Allowing us to sum the range matched by the two values.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done fairly easily by using INDEX/MATCH to find the row that matches the country, then SUMIFS to sum the amounts which are in the date range

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX($B$2:$H$10,MATCH(C13,$A$2:$A$10,0),0),$B$1:$H$1,">="&A13,$B$1:$H$1,"<="&B13)
```

[image]